# how to remove all special characters in mysql query

Tags: mysql

How to remove all special characters in mysql query

ex:

```
Table name : Feedback,  
Field name : Comments, 
Values : ("Thank's For U@r U-pd"ate"),
```

Comment: have look here:   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135776/mysql-how-to-remove-special-characters-from-column-in-query

Comment: using mysqli_real_escape_string($str)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Comments, '[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+', '') 
FROM Feedback
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea037dac7dc36f0f40cf97c56fccee8b)